# Persistent USB / Macbook / Wifi missing on reboot

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook, persistence

I made a bootable SSD with Mac Linux USB Loader. Persistence has also been created.
On first boot everything goes well. There is no wifi available but choosing additional (Broadcom) drivers solves the problem, wifi appears and I can connect. All good.
If I then shut down and restart the additional drivers remain checked (so the persistence is working) BUT this time there is still no wifi available. Unchecking and rechecking the driver changes nothing.
Can anyone suggest how to solve this? I'm not an expert, just using lockdown time to re-investigate Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Persistent live drives start the kernel drivers (typically for wifi and graphics) before the overlay for persistence is activated. This means that you cannot use a proprietary driver for wifi.

### Workaround

You can **install** Ubuntu into the USB drive [almost] like you would install it into an internal drive. This is much easier if you unplug, disconnect or disable the internal drive(s) before doing it. Otherwise it is likely that the bootloader will be written into the internal drive (particularly if you boot in UEFI mode).

Such an installed system in a USB drive is rather portable, particularly if you do not install any proprietary hardware driver. You do this in order to install a proprietary Broadcom driver, so the wifi may not work in other computers.

### Link

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)